# Ungrouping UITableView Section Header when Header is top of view

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am currently working on a UITableViewController. My current implementation includes a header view (white view), a UITableView section header (red view) and tableview (grey). Currently the TableView style is grouped so the Section Header scrolls with the TableView when scrolling up to shrink the header view.

I am trying to keep the Section Header at the top of the view when the header view goes offscreen, and allow the UITableViewCells to scroll under the Section Header. Currently the tableview cannot scroll up once the Section Header reaches the top of the view. Any suggestions would be super helpful

[image]

[image]

Current Code:

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection     section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 106.0
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let view1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 106.0))
    view1.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    return view1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return  80.0
}

override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let maxOffset = (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height)
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y >=  maxOffset {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x, y: maxOffset)
    }

    if scrollView.contentOffset.y >= 35.0 {
        scrollView.contentOffset = CGPoint(x: scrollView.contentOffset.x, y: 35.0)
    }
}
}
```

Comment: why don't you use [`plain`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewstyle/1614968-plain) table view instead? Headers don't float in grouped table views.

Comment: To implement this functionality you should use UIViewController. You can easily achieve this in UIViewController why complicate things using UITableViewController.

Comment: The plain table view doesn't scroll the SectionHeader when its in the middle of the view. It remains in the same place

Comment: @Priyansh this has nothing to do with using UIViewController over UITableViewController. OP just wants the section headers to float when the table view is scrolling which can be done easily with *.plain* table views.

Comment: @ozgur I am looking for the section to header to float ONLY when the Section Header at the top of the view. The .plain table view does not achieve this

Comment: @AndrewWalz did you set the white view as `tableView.tableHeaderView`?

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to do but you can't do it with table view as it doesn't allow you to change its scrolling behavior. What you need is a collection view with custom layout so you can stop section headers (actually supplementary views) from going up as the collection view scrolls up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not completely sure I follow what you are trying to accomplish, but please allow me to attempt to infer and feel free to provide clarifications. I like the table view practice :)

As I understand it:

1) You want the white view, the red view, and the table cells beneath the red view to scroll upward from the default position

2) You want the white view to scroll out of visibility

3) You want the red view to float at the top while the cells scroll beneath it

4) You currently have the white view as a table header, the red view as a section header, and the gray area are table cells

Sounds like a cool app!

Why not use 2 table sections:

1) Drop the table header

2) Set the white view in cell 0 section 0 of the table view.

3) Set table delegate methods so section 0 will have a nil header with 0 height

3.5) Also set the table delegate methods so section 1 will be your main table

4) Use UITableViewStylePlain so section 1 header will float at the top

Is this the desired functionality?

Comment: Thats a pretty neat implementation. I am going to try it out

Comment: Let me know how it works, and feel free to accept if you like it :)

Answer (score 2):

I was able to replicate your desired behaviour without using the `scrollViewDidScroll` method, however the `headerView` will no longer scroll with the `tableView`. You could use the `scrollViewDidScroll` method to change the height/origin of the `headerView` when the content offset is less than zero.

```
class TableViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var headerView: UIView?
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView? {
        didSet {
            tableView?.dataSource = self
            tableView?.delegate = self
        }
    }

    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int { return 1 }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { return 10 }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = UITableViewCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.gray;

        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

        let header = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.frame.width, height: 50))

        header.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

        return header
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat { return 100 }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat { return 60 }
}
```

[image: storyboard]

Comment: Im not sure how this solution is the desired behaviour. The header does not stay on the top of the view but goes off screen

Comment: Do you require the white header to be the `tableViewHeader` or can it just be an `@IBOutlet` in the view controller?

Comment: Yes it doesn't have to be a header. Any view will do

Comment: are you using a navigation controller by any chance?

Comment: No navigation controller.

Comment: I am missing the part where the header view (red) scrolls to the top of the screen before staying at the top

Comment: I suppose all this VC needs is increase the tableview size when scrolling down until it reaches the top. Any suggestions?

Comment: You said 'The header does not stay on the top of the view but goes off screen'. By header, do you mean the white table header?

Comment: You also need to make sure the table view is plain

Comment: I have tested your code. The table view does not grow in size (while the white section shrinks) until it reaches the top of the view. The tableview is plain